# Read Ahead value automatically getting updated at boot

Tags: linux, boot, startup, block-device, rc.local

OS version: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

I have the following commands in my rc.local file:

```
/usr/sbin/blockdev --report > /root/test_boot
/usr/sbin/blockdev --setra 256 /dev/vdb
/usr/sbin/blockdev --report >> /root/test_boot
```

After booting the /root/test_boot file has following content:

> cat test_boot

```
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/vda
rw   256   512  4096       2048      8588886016   /dev/vda1
rw   256   512  4096          0     53687091200   /dev/vdb
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/vda
rw   256   512  4096       2048      8588886016   /dev/vda1
rw   256   512  4096          0     53687091200   /dev/vdb
```

whereas the command

> blockdev --report

gives a different value:

```
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw  8192   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/vda
rw  8192   512  4096       2048      8588886016   /dev/vda1
rw  8192   512  4096          0     53687091200   /dev/vdb
```

So it seems that some other kernel program is overwriting the value at boot. What could be the program? Is there some way that I can execute the blockdev --setra command at the very end of the boot process?

Note: I've also tried putting the commands in init.d, systemd and crontab. Same thing happens all the times.

Comment: Linux distribution that you are using?

Comment: Linux version: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable readahead value in tuned.conf.
2. Run these commands to reload the tuned.conf file:

   ```
   # tuned-adm profile
   # tuned-adm active virtual-guest
   ```

After this the values will load from /etc/rc.d/rc.local file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ouput of `cat /etc/rc.local` from a centos 7 server.

```
#!/bin/bash
# THIS FILE IS ADDED FOR COMPATIBILITY PURPOSES
#
# It is highly advisable to create own systemd services or udev rules
# to run scripts during boot instead of using this file.
#
# In contrast to previous versions due to parallel execution during boot
# this script will NOT be run after all other services.
#
# Please note that you must run 'chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local' to ensure
# that this script will be executed during boot.
```

Comment: The symlink between files /etc/rc.local and /etc/rc.d/rc.local exists. The changes are getting reflected across both the files. If I add "touch /root/dummy_file" in the rc.local file, the file is getting created!

Comment: @Shikhar Awasthi In contrast to previous versions due to parallel execution during boot this script will NOT be run after all other services.

Comment: so for versions below Centos 7, all the startup scripts used to run serially?